# Is it possible to navigate to a different screen through a screen's JS code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

This is basically what I want to do:

```
myapp.StartScreen.created = function (screen) {
    screen.getIsAdmin().then(function success() {
        this.navigate("AdminHome.lsml");
    }, function error() {
        this.navigate("UserHome.lsml");
    });
};
```

But navigating with "this.navigate" or "this.location" does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you describe your problem more specificly? What do you mean by "Screen"? Do you mean a webpage, or a monitor device? Or what.

Comment: I meant a screen as in a VS Lightswitch Screen, so you could call it a webpage.

Comment: @joepkerste could You share getIsAdmin()? I need some inspiration...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following works for me:

```
myapp.StartScreen.created = function (screen) {
    screen.getIsAdmin().then(function success() {
        this.window.location.href = '#/AdminHome/undefined/[dee7135da]';
    }, function error() {
        this.window.location.href = '#/ClientHome/undefined/[c4fb70ef3]';        
    });
};
```